# How to debug tick_sched_timer high power usage?

Tags: ubuntu, battery, power-consumption, powertop

My tick_sched_timer is using a lot of power, this is the output of powertop:

```
    The battery reports a discharge rate of 24.7 W
    The power consumed was 516 J
    The estimated remaining time is 3 hours, 0 minutes

    Summary: 2419.8 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 54.8% CPU use

    Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
      2.38 W      5.5 ms/s     600.6        Timer          tick_sched_timer
      1.15 W    294.3 ms/s     174.1        Process        [PID 3900] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 244 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 2020
      845 mW      9.0 ms/s     209.6        Process        [PID 3749] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
      615 mW      4.3 ms/s     154.0        Process        [PID 3773] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
      561 mW      7.8 ms/s     137.6        Process        [PID 3920] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 244 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 2020
      408 mW      4.8 ms/s     101.4        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
      387 mW      9.4 ms/s      94.3        Process        [PID 3906] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 244 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 2020
      340 mW      9.8 ms/s      82.2        Process        [PID 2895] /usr/share/teams/teams --type=renderer --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --enable-features=SharedArrayBuffe
      328 mW     36.8 ms/s      67.3        Process        [PID 4103] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7352 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 202
      243 mW     11.6 ms/s      56.9        Process        [PID 2518] /usr/share/teams/teams
      209 mW      8.0 ms/s      49.7        Process        [PID 3784] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
      200 mW      6.8 ms/s      47.9        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
      166 mW     10.0 ms/s      36.6        Process        [PID 3737] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
      160 mW     13.0 ms/s      32.7        Process        [PID 3774] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
      152 mW      3.8 ms/s      37.1        Process        [PID 2892] /usr/share/teams/teams --type=renderer --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --enable-features=SharedArrayBuffe
      148 mW      0.9 ms/s      37.0        kWork          engine_retire
      139 mW     19.7 ms/s      27.3        Process        [PID 3875] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 244 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 2020
      115 mW      8.4 ms/s      23.6        Process        [PID 2303] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
      113 mW      4.4 ms/s      26.8        Process        [PID 2597] /usr/share/teams/teams
      102 mW    623.3 µs/s      25.6        Interrupt      [0] HI_SOFTIRQ
     98.6 mW      1.2 ms/s      24.5        Process        [PID 3891] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 244 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 2020
     97.7 mW      6.9 ms/s      22.0        Process        [PID 4226] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 7 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7399 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 202
     96.8 mW    148.8 µs/s      24.4        kWork          idle_work_handler
     88.8 mW    291.3 µs/s      22.4        Process        [PID 11] [rcu_sched]
     84.3 mW      5.2 ms/s      19.3        Process        [PID 5261] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 12 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7445 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 20
     81.2 mW      1.1 ms/s      20.1        Interrupt      [17] idma64.1
     71.8 mW      0.9 ms/s      17.8        Process        [PID 4249] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 7 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7399 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 202
     71.4 mW      3.0 ms/s      16.9        Process        [PID 2188] /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim
     65.3 mW     12.2 ms/s      10.8        Process        [PID 2064] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose
     59.6 mW      0.8 ms/s      14.8        Process        [PID 4126] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7352 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 202
     56.0 mW      1.6 ms/s      13.6        Process        [PID 5333] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 13 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 7493 -prefMapSize 220560 -parentBuildID 20
     53.0 mW    127.3 µs/s      13.4        kWork          psi_avgs_work
```

Do you have any idea how could I figure out what causes this issue?

Comment: Similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217980/high-power-consumption-through-btusb-and-tick-sched-timer

Comment: Unfortunately not, for me bluetooth is disabled.

Comment: I figured out that nvidia card was the reason, but the question still remains, how to decide what causes this other than guessing?